# How to I assign an imported STl file to a variable, polygon, or otherwise manipulate it?

Tags: openscad

I have 2 STL files that I want to chop, rotate, and glue together.  If I printed them and literally chopped and glued them together, I would be done.  Very simple operations.

I imported them both into OpenSCAD, but I can't find docs or figure out a way to do anything to the STL files once they are imported.  They imported fine.  I don't know how to assign a variable name to the imported object, which I presume is the next step before I can rotate and move the objects around.  I might be going in the wrong direction though, I don't know.  usually during an import of a module you can assign a variable name, or instantiate it.  Since the import also instantiates it, I'm at a loss for what to do next.  I've programmed in a smattering of languages, but haven't touched OpenSCAD in ~3+ years.

When searching, I find a cornucopia of slightly related information like how to import a file from 2011, but nothing about how to work with it once it's been imported.

Answer (score 1):

One can create a module to import the respective STL files.

> module bring_it_on_1() {
>
> import("c:/user/models/egg_on_face.stl");
>
> }
>
> translate([-10, 20, 0])
>
> bring_it_on_1();

Other modifiers can be used and will act on the STL file appropriately.

Comment: The OpenSCAD forum has a discussion regarding this topic: http://forum.openscad.org/Working-with-imported-STLs-td23840.html which includes a link to a program to convert STL to OpenSCAD, which may reduce or eliminate the problem you experience.